# How can I subtract from the previous total amount?

Tags: mysql, sql

Query Result

| date_created | sub_total | total_amount | budget_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 10000 |  |
| 2022-09-25 | 700 | 9300 | 1 |
| 2022-09-21 | 500 | 8800 | 1 |
| 2022-09-15 | 900 | 7900 | 1 |
| 2022-09-01 | 500 | 7400 | 1 |
|  |  | 7400 |  |

Budget Table

| id | budget |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10000 |

Here's my query

```
SELECT date_created, sub_total,
budget - LAG(sub_total) OVER (ORDER BY date_created DESC) 
as total_amount
FROM sales
LEFT JOIN budget_table ON budget.id = sales.budget_id
WHERE budget_id = 1
ORDER BY date_created DESC
```

[image: Here's a sample image representation]

Comment: do you have any ordering column?

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check

Comment: Yes sorry, wait let me edit my post

Comment: can use lag() @PeterParker

Comment: it looks like you're not order by the date_created @PeterParker

Comment: I use lag but it seems it can't display the first row and the last row

Comment: @PeterParker can you include what you've tried before in your ques?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially "5. Some Additional Suggestions".

Comment: Does your Sales Table contains non-filled (NULL? empty string?) column values? Read the article by provided link carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union to get start and end position and subtract cumulative sum from budget to get detail (lag is inappropriate here). prepend a seq to assist ordering

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;

CREATE TABLE T
(date_created DATE,SUB_TOTAL INT,BUDGET_ID INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('2022-09-25'   ,700,   1),
('2022-09-21'   ,500,   1),
('2022-09-15'   ,900,   1),
('2022-09-01'   ,500,   1);

CREATE TABLE T1(BUDGET_ID INT,BUDGET INT);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,10000);

SELECT 2 SEQ,T.BUDGET_ID,date_created, sub_total,
BUDGET - SUM(sub_total) OVER (ORDER BY date_created DESC) TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM T
LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.budget_id = T.budget_id
WHERE T.budget_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS SEQ, T1.BUDGET_ID,NULL,NULL,T1.BUDGET FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS SEQ, T.BUDGET_ID,NULL,NULL, 
BUDGET - SUM(sub_total) TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM T
LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.budget_id = T.budget_id
WHERE T.budget_id = 1
ORDER BY BUDGET_ID,SEQ,date_created DESC



+-----+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| SEQ | BUDGET_ID | date_created | sub_total | TOTAL_AMOUNT |
+-----+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
|   1 |         1 | NULL         |      NULL |        10000 |
|   2 |         1 | 2022-09-25   |       700 |         9300 |
|   2 |         1 | 2022-09-21   |       500 |         8800 |
|   2 |         1 | 2022-09-15   |       900 |         7900 |
|   2 |         1 | 2022-09-01   |       500 |         7400 |
|   3 |         1 | NULL         |      NULL |         7400 |
+-----+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
6 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```